# Is it possible with any payment interface to keep cards on file to charge on demand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net, activemerchant

I'm making a site for a coaching company, and they've requested that we somehow keep card information on file (I informed them that that is a big no-no, and most payment API's will handle that side of things for us) so that we can charge the cards 'on-demand'. For example, the person shows up to a coaching session, types in a pin, and it charges their card for one session. 
Best case scenario- this also works for an online store as well for payment processing. Once the card is on file, they can create a card, punch in their password, and they are good to go. 
We are currently using Authorize.net with Ruby on Rails. I'm still fairly new to the development world, and this is my first time needing to handle payment processing. As far as I have seen, there isn't as much documentation as there should be. They would prefer not to use Stripe, as it has high per-charge fees, and most of our fees are $8-$15, and they also want to avoid PayPal, as it has been known to freeze accounts for no good reason.

Comment: 2.9% + $0.30 per charge is "high"? If you can't absorb that, you've got problems with your business plan. You'll also get murdered on charge-backs, which can be 5% of more depending on your vertical.

Comment: @tadman I tried to explain that... They tell me $0.60 per transaction is a lot when you have upwards of 40 transactions a day...

Comment: "$5 an hour is a lot to pay a programmer when they work upwards of 40 hours a week." It's called the cost of doing business. Stripe's fees aren't much higher than what a provider like Authorize.net charges directly, so I don't have any idea what the problem is here. Saving a couple of bucks and exposing your customers to high levels of financial risk is not acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing credit card information on your side is not practical for two reasons - security and cost (PCI compliance). Your best option is to use Stripe or Braintree.

Both offer great libraries and work as payment aggregators (no need for a merchant account with a bank to start processing payments).

https://stripe.com/docs/api#cards

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/sdk/server/payment-method-management/create

Comment: Agreed. When people look at the costs for taking online payments, they often ignore the costs of providing security. I have worked for a large e-Commerce site which still chose to outsource precisely because PCI would cost more to implement than the fees of using an external provider. I also worked for a PCI tier 1 organisation whose main reason to exist was to handle that for their clients - the security ethos inside the latter company was far more stringent and costly to maintain (but of course it was worth it, because the cost scaled across multiple clients once set up).

Comment: I agree, but both require either PCI compliance, or transaction-to-transaction payment processing, so we can't do 'quick buys'.
Still looking for a solution, but it appears Authorize.net has some sort of workaround that I am reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

For Authorize.Net, you would use Customer Information Manager for secure data storage.  http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/starting_guide.html#customerInfoManagerID